# A (document).click function is causing a glitch in my dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, jquery

**Codepen**: http://codepen.io/JTBennett/pen/MKXjdO

**Issue**:

```
$(document).on('click', function (e) {
    if($(e.target).closest('.treatments, .info').length == 0){
        if($(".treatments, .info").is(":visible")) {
            $(".treatments, .info").fadeOut("fast")
        }
    }
});
```

So, everything here is functioning how I want it to except when you click on the dropdown items (.treatments & .info), the submenu immediately disappears. This is due to the code above which is meant to tell the submenu to disappear when you've clicked anywhere in the document EXCEPT on the elements themselves, and ONLY if the elements are visible.

I'm going to try changing the order of the conditions of the function to see if I can get anywhere with that, but I'm running out of ideas with this one.

Comment: stop propagation of the click - edit, wait, looks like you are, never mind  =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `$.slideOut()` method. You're getting an error on the console. Change it to a `$.slideUp` and it works fine.  http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yeEVjq

```
// $(".info").slidePut("fast");
$(".info").slideUp("fast");
```

Always check your console!

Comment: I always feel stupid when I post something here - thanks for catching that.

Comment: Self deprecating sarcasm always helps when I feel that way ;)